# plot points with by group in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I am trying to plot points using a by argument in R data.table - the plan is to colour the points by the grouping variable, but in development I noticed a behaviour I thought was strange. With data.table, the operation in `j` (of `DT[i, j, by]`) is supposed to be carried out per level in the `by`, e.g.

```
library(data.table)
dtcars <- copy(mtcars)
setDT(dtcars)
dtcars[, mean(mpg), by=cyl]
```

But I am now trying to get this to plot points for each level of cyl separately. The black points are showing what data should be getting plotted in red, but it only seems to do those where cyl is 8 when I use the by

```
dtcars[, plot(mpg~hp, typ="n")]
dtcars[, points(mpg~hp, col="black")]
dtcars[, points(mpg~hp, col="red"), by=cyl]
```

**Any idea what is going on, why it is only acting on the one value of cyl and how to have R plot points for all levels of cyl, with by?** I've used data.table a lot and not noticed this behaviour before.

---

Bonus points if you can tell me how to return the index of the by value so I can index the colours giving the same effect as

```
dtcars[, points(mpg~hp, col=c("red", "blue", "green")[as.factor(cyl)])]
```

Becoming something like

```
dtcars[, points(mpg~hp, col=c("red", "blue", "green")[by_index]), by=cyl]
```

Comment: Why dont you use `dtcars[, points(mpg~hp, col=cyl)]`? For the group index, check `?.GRP`

Comment: that works for this example, but the plan is to go further and to a point where I need the bys to work - I'm mainly just curious as to why the by behaviour isn't working as expected

Comment: also thanks for .GRP and the other special characters that search gave me @talat

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using `ggplot2` instead of base R for plotting? If so, try the following :

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "cyl") +
  theme_linedraw()
```